# Index is out of range on main

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to make one sdk working however is in objective C and. I am very new to this..like two hours. Index is out of range on main I guess means that some page is missing ?

Thread 1 index is out of range

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    NSString * appDelegateClassName;
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Setup code that might create autoreleased objects goes here.
        appDelegateClassName = NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]);
    }
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, appDelegateClassName);
}
```

Edit

I am using simulator and the exception is in this first line

```
SettingHandler *videoFormat = [[SettingHandler alloc] initWithTitle:@"Video format" key:@"video_format" type:@"picker"];
    HNfvcVideoFormat *formats;
    NInt formatCount = 1;
    NFaceVerificationClientGetAvailableVideoFormats(&formats, &formatCount);
    NSMutableArray *formatList = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < formatCount; i++) {
        NUInt width;
        NUInt height;
        NFloat fps;
        NFaceVerificationClientVideoFormatGetWidth(formats[i], &width);
        NFaceVerificationClientVideoFormatGetHeight(formats[i], &height);
        NFaceVerificationClientVideoFormatGetFrameRate(formats[i], &fps);
        [formatList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d x %d @ %d", width, height, (int)fps]];
    }
    
    [videoFormat setOptions:formatList];
```

and another here

SettingHandler *icaoSettings = [[SettingHandler alloc] initWithTitle:@"ICAO Settings" key:nil type:@"title"];

Comment: Problem could be anywhere - it just shows that it comes from here as this is at the highest level, but I don't think it is here ... e.g. if you say 1 + ( 1 + ( 1 + ( 1 + ( 1 / 0 ) ) ) ) is wrong it is because much deeper the 1 / 0. is wrong .. this just says something is wrong but it is not specifically where the trouble is...

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint. This will hopefully show you the location (close to) where the crash occurs.

Post more details of the crash, because the code you've shown is correct; Xcode simply points to `main()` because the run-time exception signal was not caught elsewhere.